# Temperature Dependent Frequency of Relaxation Oscillator

Tags: oscillator, comparator

I built a relaxation oscillator to convert a capacitance into a variable frequency square wave. The passive components have a very small temperature coefficient, but when we change the temperature of the LM2903HYPT comparator the frequency shifts by around 8kHz. How do changes in the comparator cause the frequency of the circuit to change? It normally operates at around 150kHz or so. How can I remove these temperature dependent changes in future designs?
[image: Schematic]
Thanks!
-Hunter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attraction of that type of relaxation oscillator is that the output voltage goes back to both the timing capacitor *and* the threshhold setting resistors, so to first order, the actual value of output voltage does not matter.

Comparators are not precision parts. This one has typical propagation delays in 0.3 to 1uS, depending on overdrive. Your half period of 3uS is not much more than that, so any small changes in delay will cause proportionately large variations. A second order effect of the change in output voltage will be a change in slew rate, which would change the propagation delay.

If you increase the value of R11 by an order of magnitude, it will increase the period of the oscillator, which should reduce the magnitude of variations in comparator delay. Unfortunately I would expect it to increase delay variation (but not as much as a factor of 10) as it reduces the slew rate.

Check out [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281920/why-do-comparators-generally-have-higher-offset-voltages-than-opamps/281924#281924) answer which suggests using one or more amplifiers to increase the slew rate before a comparator. Reducing the frequency, then increasing the slew rate with an amplifier, could well give you much better temperature sensitivity. An amplifier with adequate GBW will have its performance almost completely controlled by the gain setting resistors, rather than thrashing around open loop as a comparator does. Note this is not using the amplifier *as* a comparator, merely as a slope amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

The **saturation voltage** of the [comparator](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/44/f7/9d/99/42/20/45/fd/CD00000534.pdf/files/CD00000534.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000534.pdf) is one obvious contributor. The comparator will also have some **offset voltage shift** with temperature, the **bias current** will change, and the **response time** will change.

[image]

If I was going to make a wild-a** guess I would say it's probably the **response time**, which will be probably several microseconds with a ramping input (note that the time is specified as 1.3usec *typical*, only at 25°C, and with an overdrive of 100mV) -- so a change of only maybe +/-100ns will account for your measured change.

The output voltage could too, but only with a rather large change in temperature (which you did not deign to mention- it's kind of important).

---

What you can do to make it better next time- control the voltage that sets the thresholds and the integration current better, pick a comparator that is much faster than the required switching time and that has very good DC stability.

As an out-of-the box suggestion, you can get much better performance even with a crap circuit by making two circuits or switching inputs so that you measure your unknown capacitance and a reference NP0 capacitor. This will also cancel out some other sources of error such as resistor drift (use 5% resistors if you want), and even a certain amount of power supply noise. That's what I would consider if I was making a whole bunch of them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much! Both of your suggestions were very helpful. I tried replacing R11 by a 118K resistor. This brought the oscillating frequency down to about 20-30kHz and seemed to greatly reduce the temperature dependence.

Thanks so much!
-Hunter

Comment: Don't use answers to say "thank you". See [tour](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) how SE EE works and how to mark good answers.